# How to get list of object from S3 AWS using listObjectV2 and NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the list of all my objects store in S3 But I am getting following error:

```
message: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.',
code: 'SignatureDoesNotMatch',
region: 'eu-west-1',
time: 2020-01-05T19:24:50.205Z,
requestId: '28764D898F55C5DE',
extendedRequestId: '6Z96KWfpOnjzFUJ6KTy+FSI7DReLb+t1h4wKQczGKYPtaNLAwNhjdUZU+oi/xK1ni7L0+c4xtJ4=',
cfId: undefined,
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 5.358774772131336
```

My code is below, Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')

async function trigger() {
    try
    {
        aws.config.setPromisesDependency();

        aws.config.update({
            accessKeyId:'xxxxxx',
            secretAccessKey:'xxxxxxx',
            region:'eu-west-1'
        });

        const s3 = new aws.S3();

        const response = await s3.listObjectsV2({
            Bucket: 'nikhilkrdwivedi'
        }).promise();

        console.log("response:",response)
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("our error ",e )
    }
}

trigger()
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious bugs. Are you using an up to date aws-sdk? Does the awscli (`aws s3 ls s3://nikhilkrdwivedi`) work with these same credentials? Note that you typically do not have to call `setPromisesDependency()` in order to use native promises.

Comment: please make sure the server/machine dates are in sync. sometimes out of dates can cause signature mismatch prpblem